# Download PDF file from iPad

Tags: ipad, pdf, download

I have a server side component (i.e. a Servlet) that creates a PDF file and sent it back to the browser with this response header:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "cache");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "cache");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=document.pdf");
```

All works fine in all browser except on iPad. On iPad the content is showed but the browser does not ask me if I want to save the file.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: When you donwload the PDF does it get the correct name? We cannot do it correctly, it allways goes like G028jdeo3u3d_.pdf even with the content disposition...

Comment: Nop. We too have to download it with a name (e.g. QL-sxzrtf13yC) that does not correspond to the name defined in the content disposition directive. If you find how to set it ;)

Comment: If you add at the end of the href "&filename=/myfilename.pdf" it modify the black barcode to see it on iBooks but the title of the webpage not. I guess that putting the right Content-Disposion it may be be posible change the title of the webpage and then download the document with the right name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found that it was the correct ipda behaviour: if is not installed any program that can handle pdf (e.g. FileApp) safari shows the preview in a read-only mode.
If it is installed a program that can handle those files safari prompts for what to do on those file.

Massimo

Answer (score 0):

if you want to download the right name of the PDF file you need to edit the metadata of the PDF file. As you introduce the title of the document, you may put the Author and more details in the Metadata. You can see the info in Windows looking at the properties. It is posible to edit that metadata downloading a free program like http://www.becyhome.de/download_eng.htm#becypdfmetaedit.

I hope it helps you!.

Good luck.

Carlos